# How to add multiple video players linked to firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I am trying to make a page of youtube,twitch and instagram videos. The urls are stored in a firebase collecton called videos as documents. Each document has the video name, url, type and a short description. I can retrieve all of these urls easily but now I want to convert them to videos. Does anyone have any idea how to do that? I tried to use the video_player plugin but it requires me to use controllers and as there are x number of videos, making a lot of controllers does not seem like the correct way to go.I know this maybe easy but I cannot get head around it. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much head scratching, I decided to leave this. Then I got a problem where I had to add a button to go to the channel and to store that data, I had to create a custom widget which could store it. Then it hit me I could do the same for videos. I'll post the code when I make it(within a week). But just wanted to show that I got the answer

Comment: So how did you make multiple controllers for multiple videos?

Comment: Basically I used a new stateful widget to create a video, so each widget stores its own data. If you need the code let me know